# Gatsby: getImage returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

getImage is returning undefined so my GatsbyImage component is not rendered.

File structure:

- src/pages/gallery.js
- src/images (has 12 photos named photo-01.jpg, photo-02.jpg, ...)

I have the following code (gallery.js):

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

const Gallery = () => {
  const { gallery } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      gallery: allFile(
        filter: {
          extension: { eq: "jpg" }
          absolutePath: { regex: "/images/" }
        }
      ) {
        nodes {
          id
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h1 className="text-gastby mb-4">Gallery</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {gallery.nodes.map((image) => (
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3" key={image.id}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(image.childImageSharp.fluid)}
                alt="Gallery"
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

what can i have wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) (from Gatsby 1 to Gatsby 2) and [`gatsby-plugin-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) (from Gatsby 3 onwards). The first one is now deprecated.

This can be easily spotted when you query for `fluid` or `fixed` GraphQL nodes since they are created by `gatsby-image` which uses `Img` (`from 'gatsby-image`') component, which accepts a `fluid` or `fixed` property.

On the other hand, `gatsby-plugin-image` queries for `gatsbyImageData` (not `fluid` or `fixed`) and the corresponding `GatsbyImage` (`from 'gatsby-plugin-image'`) component accepts an `image` property.

In your case, you are querying a `gatsby-image` structure applied in a `gatsby-plugin-image` component, that's why it is returning `undefined`.

Check the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/) but essentially you will need to replace (and remove) all references to `gatsby-image` and install the required dependencies:

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-image gatsby-plugin-sharp gatsby-transformer-sharp
```

Add it to your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

And change your query to something like:

```
const Gallery = () => {
  const { gallery } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      gallery: allFile(
        filter: {
          extension: { eq: "jpg" }
          absolutePath: { regex: "/images/" }
        }
      ) {
        nodes {
          id
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container py-5">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h1 className="text-gastby mb-4">Gallery</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {gallery.nodes.map((image) => (
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3" key={image.id}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(image.childImageSharp)}
                alt="Gallery"
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

*Double-check the query since the nodes and the structure may be different when applying `gatsby-plugin-image`.*

Note that [`getImage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#getimage) is a helper function and you may not need it, consider using directly:

```
  <GatsbyImage
    image={image.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData}
    alt="Gallery"
  />
```

Comment: Thanks Ferran Buireu! I found the Gastby documentation a bit confusing, but you explained it to me very clearly.